# Update en PostgreSQL con resultado de Select

Tags: postgresql, sql, subconsultas

quiero hacer la actualización de un campo en una tabla.
Actualmente luce así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El último número del campo "referencia" corresponde al "idtitular".

Necesito actualizar el campo "referencia" a que diga "T202100-idtitular".

Por ejemplo en el primer registro, que quede "T202100-1".

Es una cantidad grande de registros, por lo que intenté hacer una consulta anidada:

```
 UPDATE "TORRDBV1".tb_toroparking set referencia = (select concat('T202100-', idtitular) from "TORRDBV1".tb_toroparking);
```

Si lo uso con un where para que sea un sólo registro, funciona bien, pero al quitar la condición me devuelve este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería que alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: a modo de prueba crea una columna con nombre referencia2 asi puedes probar esto sin afectar la columna referencia:

UPDATE   tb_toroparking
SET      referencia2 = referencia || '-' || idtitular

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta. 
Justo acabo de lograr lo que necesitaba usando la función REPLACE.
Lo anotaré por aquí por si a alguien le sirve.

Comment: Bien ahi Valeria. Buenas noticias que lo hayas logrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que el texto es constante y solo varía el ID, puedes concatenar directamente el ID en cada fila con un `update` simple:

```
update "TORRDBV1".tb_toroparking 
   set referencia = concat('T202100-', idtitular);
```

Eso tomará el `idTitular` de cada fila y te irá devolviendo `'T202100-1'`, `'T202100-2'`.. `'T202100-N'` según corresponda.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Me pareció bastante simple ahora que lo explicas.

Answer (score 0):

Logré lo que necesitaba usando la función REPLACE

```
 UPDATE "TORRDBV1".tb_toroparking set referencia =  REPLACE(referencia, 'T202000', 'T202100');
```

Actualicé los valores de "referencia" con el valor resultante de un REPLACE.
Busque "T202000" en "referencia" y lo reemplacé por "T202100", quedando el último valor intacto.